# Wedge Product: Vectors wedged with Multivectors? (Disclaimer: Music theory ahead)

Tags: matrices, exterior-algebra, music-theory

The Xenharmonic Wiki is a great resource to start understanding and, if enough determination is available, constructing temperaments as well as scales. As some of you may know, this Wiki is *not* beginner friendly.

With that out of the way, let's get to the question: On the page ["Optimal patent val"](https://en.xen.wiki/w/Optimal_patent_val) the author(s) state that

> Given any collection of p-limit commas, there is a finite list of p-limit patent vals tempering out the commas. [...] [A]mong these patent vals will be found the unique patent val which has the lowest TE error.

Naturally, I tried to find out how to calculate the Tenney-Euclidean Error with the help of the [corresponding page](https://en.xen.wiki/w/Tenney-Euclidean_temperament_measures). After some fiddling around, I figured out that the wedge products are calculated with the standard vector basis (?) and [this](https://en.xen.wiki/w/Wedgies_and_Multivals) page shows a kind of tongue-in-cheek way to calculate the produt for two "1-vals" (vectors). On a side note, [this paper](http://x31eq.com/te.pdf) demonstrates a way to calculate the complexity just using vectors and matrices.
These are the equations given above:

$\sqrt{\det{[\frac{MW^2M^T}{HW^2H^T}}]}$ for the temperament complexity

$\sqrt{\det{[\frac{MW^2M^T}{HW^2H^T}(1+E^2_k)-\frac{MW^2H^THW^2M^T}{(HW^2H^T)^2}}]}$ for the temperament "badness"

The error is simply the quotient of the complexity and the "badness".

$M$ describes the val that contains the mapping of the generator (usually one step of an EDO) to the $\log_2$ of the primes up to a prime-limit.

$H$ is a row vector containing said $\log_2$ of the primes.

$W$ is a square weighting matrix that, for "Tenney weighting", just contains the reciprocal of the values described for $H$ on its diagonal.

Lastly, $E_k$ is the smallest error that you care about, so it is a free parameter.

For complexity, you just wedge all starting vals together and call the result matrix $M$ (and take the norm if you want to know about it). For badness, it simply is the norm of the wedge product of the matrix $M$ with $J$ (a vector with all entries being 1).

Now, the paper gives a way to calculate "badness" without the wedge product (as you can see above), but how would I go about calculating "complexity" and "badness" without cheesing my way through the calculation? Since wedging this multivector (I presume) with a vector makes... little sense to me. Hence the question.

At last, I know that the wedge (a.k.a. exterior) product is dependent on the used basis, but an intuitive explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you'd include the most relevant information here. Some people don't want to bother clicking on the links.

Comment: Okay, I'll add some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll rephrase the definitions from your links in terms of abstract linear algebra (no matrices).

A monzo (vector/ket) $\vec x$ can be written as

$$\vec x=|x_2\;x_3\;x_5\;x_7\;\cdots\;x_{p_n}\rangle=x_2\vec b_2+x_3\vec b_3+x_5\vec b_5+\cdots$$

which corresponds to the number $2^{x_2}\cdot3^{x_3}\cdot5^{x_5}\cdots$ .

A val (covector/bra) $\vec f$ can be written as

$$\vec f=\langle f_2\;f_3\;f_5\cdots|=f_2\vec\alpha_2+f_3\vec\alpha_3+f_5\vec\alpha_5+\cdots.$$

The sets $\{\vec b_p\}$ and $\{\vec\alpha_p\}$ are [dual bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis), so that $\vec\alpha_p(\vec b_p)=1$ and otherwise $\vec\alpha_p(\vec b_q)=0$.

The basis monzos are defined to be orthogonal, and to have Euclidean norm $\lVert\vec b_p\rVert_E=\log_2 p$, so they can be made into an orthonormal basis:

$$\hat b_p=\frac{\vec b_p}{\log_2 p};\quad\lVert\hat b_p\rVert_E=1.$$

The Euclidean dot product on monzos induces a dot product on vals, according to which the basis vals are orthogonal, and have norm $\lVert\vec\alpha_p\rVert_E=1/\log_2 p$, so they can also be made into an orthonormal basis:

$$\hat\alpha_p=\vec\alpha_p\log_2 p;\quad\lVert\hat\alpha_p\rVert_E=1,$$

and they're still dual to each other: $\hat\alpha_p(\hat b_p)=1$.

The weighted coordinates of $\vec x$ are the coefficients with respect to the orthonormal basis:

$$\vec x=x_2\vec b_2+x_3\vec b_3+x_5\vec b_5+\cdots=\big(x_2\big)\hat b_2+\big(x_3\log_23\big)\hat b_3+\big(x_5\log_25\big)\hat b_5+\cdots,$$

$$\vec f=f_2\vec\alpha_2+f_3\vec\alpha_3+f_5\vec\alpha_5+\cdots=\big(f_2\big)\hat\alpha_2+\Big(\frac{f_3}{\log_23}\Big)\hat\alpha_3+\Big(\frac{f_5}{\log_25}\Big)\hat\alpha_5+\cdots.$$

The exterior algebra of multimonzos has a basis

$$\{1,\\ \hat b_2,\;\hat b_3,\;\hat b_5,\;\cdots,\\ \hat b_2\wedge\hat b_3,\;\hat b_2\wedge\hat b_5,\;\hat b_3\wedge\hat b_5,\;\cdots,\\ \hat b_2\wedge\hat b_3\wedge\hat b_5,\;\cdots,\\ \vdots\quad\},$$

which also turns out to be orthonormal, according to the dot product defined by the Gramian determinant:

$$\big(\vec x_1\wedge\vec x_2\wedge\cdots\wedge\vec x_r\big)\star\big(\vec y_1\wedge\vec y_2\wedge\cdots\wedge\vec y_r\big)=\det[\vec x_i\cdot\vec y_j].$$

(There's an equivalent definition in terms of geometric algebra; see a recent answer of mine.) This expression is essentially the same as that for applying a multival to a set of monzos:

$$\big(\vec f_1\wedge\vec f_2\wedge\cdots\wedge\vec f_r\big)\big(\vec y_1,\vec y_2,\cdots,\vec y_r\big)=\det[\vec f_i(\vec y_j)].$$

The Euclidean norm of a multimonzo or multival is $\lVert M\rVert_E=\sqrt{M\star M}$. The Tenney-Euclidean norm, or complexity, is

$$\lVert M\rVert_{TE}=\frac{\lVert M\rVert_E}{\sqrt{\binom{n}{r}}}=\sqrt\frac{M\star M}{\left(\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}\right)}.$$

The badness of the multival $M$ is defined as $\lVert J\wedge M\rVert_{TE}$, in terms of the val

$$J=\hat\alpha_2+\hat\alpha_3+\hat\alpha_5+\cdots+\hat\alpha_{p_n}.$$

$M$ is not a matrix. If you've been given $M$ as a function (specifying how it acts on monzos), you'll need to express it as a sum of wedge products of vals, in order to calculate its norm.

---

**Example:**

From [here](https://en.xen.wiki/w/Meantone_family#Seven_limit_children), 7-limit meantone is supposed to have the syntonic comma $(-4\vec b_2+4\vec b_3-\vec b_5)$ and $(-13\vec b_2+10\vec b_3-\vec b_7)$ in its nullspace. Any linear subspace can be represented by the wedge product of its basis vectors; even if we change the basis, the wedge product is unique up to a scale factor. So this nullspace is represented by

$$N=(-4\vec b_2+4\vec b_3-\vec b_5)\wedge(-13\vec b_2+10\vec b_3-\vec b_7)$$

$$=12\vec b_2\wedge\vec b_3-13\vec b_2\wedge\vec b_5+10\vec b_3\wedge\vec b_5+4\vec b_2\wedge\vec b_7-4\vec b_3\wedge\vec b_7+\vec b_5\wedge\vec b_7.$$

Now, to find the multival $M$ with nullspace $N$... I don't think this operation has a name... "Hodge duality", "Poincare duality", and "volume form" come to mind, but they involve too much structure. Let's call this a volume form anyway: $(\vec\alpha_2\wedge\vec\alpha_3\wedge\vec\alpha_5\wedge\vec\alpha_7)$; it represents the entire val space. We just apply this to $N$ to get $M$. In geometric algebra, this would be a fat dot product:

$$\pm M=(\vec\alpha_2\wedge\vec\alpha_3\wedge\vec\alpha_5\wedge\vec\alpha_7)\bullet N$$

$$=-12\vec\alpha_5\wedge\vec\alpha_7-13\vec\alpha_3\wedge\vec\alpha_7-10\vec\alpha_2\wedge\vec\alpha_7-4\vec\alpha_3\wedge\vec\alpha_5-4\vec\alpha_2\wedge\vec\alpha_5-\vec\alpha_2\wedge\vec\alpha_3$$

$$=-\big(\vec\alpha_2\wedge\vec\alpha_3+4\vec\alpha_2\wedge\vec\alpha_5+4\vec\alpha_3\wedge\vec\alpha_5+10\vec\alpha_2\wedge\vec\alpha_7+13\vec\alpha_3\wedge\vec\alpha_7+12\vec\alpha_5\wedge\vec\alpha_7\big).$$

Compare this with the wiki's "wedgie for septimal meantone". (I disagree with their choice of ordering.) We choose the sign so that the coefficient of $\vec\alpha_2\wedge\vec\alpha_3$ is positive, but that's not important for calculating the norm. I'll use the abbreviation $\lg=\log_2$.

$${\lVert M\rVert_E}^2=M\star M$$

$$=\Big(\frac{1}{\lg3}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{4}{\lg5}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{4}{\lg3\lg5}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{10}{\lg7}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{13}{\lg3\lg7}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{12}{\lg5\lg7}\Big)^2$$

$$\lVert M\rVert_E\approx5.4000$$

$$\lVert M\rVert_{TE}\approx2.2046\,.$$

And for your main question:

$$J=\hat\alpha_2+\hat\alpha_3+\hat\alpha_5+\hat\alpha_7$$

$$J\wedge M=\Big(\frac{4}{\lg3\lg5}-\frac{4}{\lg5}+\frac{1}{\lg3}\Big)\hat\alpha_2\wedge\hat\alpha_3\wedge\hat\alpha_5\\+\Big(\frac{13}{\lg3\lg7}-\frac{10}{\lg7}+\frac{1}{\lg3}\Big)\hat\alpha_2\wedge\hat\alpha_3\wedge\hat\alpha_7\\+\Big(\frac{12}{\lg5\lg7}-\frac{10}{\lg7}+\frac{4}{\lg5}\Big)\hat\alpha_2\wedge\hat\alpha_5\wedge\hat\alpha_7\\+\Big(\frac{12}{\lg5\lg7}-\frac{13}{\lg3\lg7}+\frac{4}{\lg3\lg5}\Big)\hat\alpha_3\wedge\hat\alpha_5\wedge\hat\alpha_7$$

$$\lVert J\wedge M\rVert_E\approx0.012435$$

$$\lVert J\wedge M\rVert_{TE}\approx0.0062175\,.$$

...Either I'm wrong, or my calculator's wrong, or the wiki's wrong. It says the badness is $0.013707$ . I tried swapping $\vec\alpha$'s with $\hat\alpha$'s (adding or removing $\lg$'s), but it still doesn't match.

I'll come back later to look for errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I understand the problem a bit better now. However, how would I go about wedging M and J together? If it is not asking too much, could you provide an example for, let's say, 7-limit meantone?

Comment: Ah, thank you! And I don't mind the "errors", your example is clear enough.